# What is the shortest type-safe way to compare objects from the same discriminated union?

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

Let's assume the existence of the following discriminated union type:

```
interface Circle {
  type: 'circle';
  radius: number;
}

interface Square {
  type: 'square';
  sideLength: number;
}

type Shape = Circle | Square;
```

I am trying to find the easiest way to implement a type-safe comparison function (i.e. without any casts or potential runtime errors), which checks if 2 objects of this union type are equivalent.

The reason why I ask is because the TS checker does NOT seem narrow the objects' types to the same concrete type when you verify that their discriminant property is the same, i.e.:

```
function areEqual(shapeA: Shape, shapeB: Shape): boolean {
  if (shapeA.type !== shapeB.type) {
    return false;
  }
   
  switch (shapeA.type) {
    case ('circle'):
      return shapeA.radius === shapeB.radius; // <- TS complains that shapeB might NOT have 'radius' property here, even though the if above guarantees that shapeA and shapeB's types are the same
    case ('square'):
    ....
  }
```

Is there any way to avoid this error?

NOTE: I understand that I can preserve type-safety by checking shapeB's type with yet another inner `switch` but this would require a lot of unnecessary code just to appease the type checker, especially if the union has more than 2 types.

Comment: TS can’t track arbitrary correlations that result from checks; its control flow analysis doesn’t act on *sets* of expressions.  I’m not sure what the least repetitive compiler-approved type safe version of this check would be right now, though.  Probably some “odd” refactoring.

Comment: I am not sure why that would classify as an arbitrary correlation, though - given that this is a check against the discriminant property (it even has its own name :). Either way, you might be right, I just wanted to double-check that I am not missing something.

Comment: With regards to the least repetitive compiler-approved version, my guess is that it's a swtich statement with nested switches within each 'case', where each nested 'switch' ONLY has a 'case' for the same type as the outer 'case' and a default that returns 'false'

Comment: You're checking the discriminant property of one object against that of another object; instead of narrowing one object's type to one of the union members, you're *conceptually* narrowing the type of, say, `[shapeA, shapeB]` to `[Circle, Circle] | [Square, Square]`, but there is no value `[shapeA, shapeB]` to speak of.  The compiler does not *arbitrarily* (hopefully the term seems more apt now) synthesize new expressions and then narrow their types. It can narrow `shapeA` or `shapeB`, but after the check both of them are still only known to be `Shape`, so no narrowing occurs.

Comment: Best I can do to not be repetitive is [this](https://tsplay.dev/m0olDN), which refactors your algorithm out into custom user-defined type guard functions which explicitly tell the compiler what to conclude from the checks, and also needs an explicit value like `[shapeA, shapeB]` to perform narrowing on.  Let me know if you want me to write this up as an answer, including the reasoning for why your version doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification - I think it's starting to click. Just to make sure I understand you: you are saying that TS can perform narrowing on a single type of expression - a single variable - so narrowing of other expressions  such as an arbitrary list of variables is NOT possible, is that correct?

Comment: Wrt your code example - there is much to unpack in terms of custom generic types (at least for me) but I don't think it meets my criterion for type-safety because the code throws a runtime error. I should have been clearer, but I am looking for a solution which contains neither any casts nor any other construct that can result in a runtime error (i.e. I want the compiler to tell me if I have NOT handled all cases). Do you think you can tweak it? My guess is no, since I don't think user-defined type guards support exhaustive checking but I could be wrong.

Comment: TypeScript has some narrowing that it does automatically, and some that you can convince it to do via type guard functions, but in almost all cases, it only narrows a *single expression*, which is usually a variable but could be a property.  It could indeed narrow a value of type `[Circle, Circle] | [Square, Square]`, but there needs to *be* such a value. The fact that two variables, which, if packaged like `[x, y]`, *would* be of that type, doesn't affect things.

Comment: The issue of whether a series of `if` statements can prevent unreachable code errors in exhaustive cases is https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21985 and right now it's not supported.  The workaround is to use an `assertNever()` function like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7Plrm).  Yes, that function throws an error, but it will be unreachable; it's better for it to be there because if you make a mistake you'll get the desired error both at compile time and at runtime.  But if you don't want it you can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/NrKRVm).

Comment: So, are you ready for an answer or am I still missing something?  BTW anything you think needs to be satisfied that isn't clear in the question should probably be [edit]ed in.

Comment: Edited the question as requested. I think it would be great if you can modify your code to support ANY union type (not just my example Shape), as long as it has the same discriminant property...but that's your call. Feel free to write this up as an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242754/discussion-between-chipilov-and-jcalz).

Comment: You can, but the generality makes it more complicated, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBjLnN). Do you want that in the answer or should I stick to `Shape`?

Comment: I think it would be best to document both - use the simpler one for your explanations but also put a note at the end with the more general one (because the general one seems very useful but also not trivial to infer from the simpler one). If, for some reason, you want to document only one - go with the simpler, I think it would make more sense  conceptually. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript's [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) is what allows the compiler to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the type of variables and properties based on checks.  But this analysis is built from a set of heuristic rules that only trigger in certain specific situations.

It does not perform a full "what-if" analysis whereby every expression of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) is hypothetically narrowed to every possible union member.  For example, inside the body of `areEqual()`, the compiler does not consider all of the following situations

- What should the types be if `shapeA` is a `Circle` and `shapeB` is a `Circle`?
- What should the types be if `shapeA` is a `Circle` and `shapeB` is a `Square`?
- What should the types be if `shapeA` is a `Square` and `shapeB` is a `Circle`?
- What should the types be if `shapeA` is a `Square` and `shapeB` is a `Square`?

If it did this, the compiler would surely be able to see that your implementation is safe.  But if it did things like this, then most non-trivial programs would probably take longer to compile than you'd be willing to wait (to put it mildly).  There just aren't enough resources to do a brute force analysis.  At one point I wished for some way to selectively opt into such analysis in limited situations (see [microsoft/TypeScript#25051](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051)) but no such feature exists in the language.  So brute force analysis is out.

The compiler doesn't have human intelligence (as of TS4.6 anyway) so it can't figure out how to abstract its analysis to a higher order.  As a human being, I can understand that once we establish `(shapeA.type === shapeB.type)`, it "ties together" `shapeA` and `shapeB` such that any subsequent check of either variable's `type` property should narrow both variables.  But the compiler does not understand this.

It only has a set of heuristics for specific situations.  For [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), if you want narrowing, you need to check the discriminant property against particular [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) constants.

There is no built-in support for your `areEqual()` scenario, most likely because it doesn't come up enough to be worth hardcoding.

---

So what can you do?  Well, TypeScript does give you the ability to write your own [user-defined type guard functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) which allow you some more fine grained control over how narrowing occurs.  But using it requires some nontrivial refactoring of your code.  For example:

```
function areEqual(...shapes: [Shape, Shape]): boolean {

  if (!hasSameType(shapes)) return false;

  if (hasType(shapes, "circle")) {
    return shapes[0].radius === shapes[1].radius;
  } else if (hasType(shapes, "square")) {
    return shapes[0].sideLength === shapes[1].sideLength;
  }

  assertNever(shapes); 
}
```

Here we are packaging the `shapeA` and `shapeB` parameters into a single `shapes` rest argument of the `[Shape, Shape]` [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions).  We need to do that because user-defined type guard functions only act on a single argument, so if we want both objects to be narrowed at once, it forces us to create a single value where that happens.

```
type SameShapeTuple<T extends Shape[], U extends Shape = Shape> =
  Extract<U extends Shape ? { [K in keyof T]: U } : never, T>;

function hasSameType<T extends Shape[]>(shapes: T): shapes is SameShapeTuple<T> {
  return shapes.every(s => s.type === shapes[0].type);
}
```

`SameShapeTuple<T>` is a helper type that takes a `Shape` array/tuple type and distributes the `Shape` union across the array type.  So `SameShapeTuple<Shape[]>` is `Circle[] | Square[]` and `SameShapeTuple<[Shape, Shape, Shape]>` is `[Circle, Circle, Circle] | [Square, Square, Square]`.  And `hasSameType()` takes an array of `shapes` of type `T` and returns `shapes is SameShapeTuple<T>`.  Inside `areEqual()`, we are using `hasSameType()` to narrow `[Shape, Shape]` to `[Circle, Circle] | [Square, Square]`.

```
function hasType<T extends SameShapeTuple<Shape[]>, K extends T[number]['type']>(
  shapes: T, type: K
): shapes is Extract<T, { type: K }[]> {
  return shapes[0]?.type === type;
}
```

The `hasType(shapes, type)` function is a type guard that will narrow a union-typed `shapes` array to whichever member of the union has elements whose `type` property matches `type`.  Inside `areEqual()`, we are using `hasType()` to narrow `[Circle, Circle] | [Square, Square]` to either `[Circle, Circle]` or `[Square, Square]` or even `never` depending the `type` parameter passed to it.

```
function assertNever(x: never): never {
  throw new Error("Expected unreachable, but got a value: " + String(x));
}
```

And finally, because you need to use `if`/`else` blocks instead of `switch` statements for user-defined type guard functions, we have `assertNever()`, which acts as an exhaustiveness check to make sure that the compiler agrees that it's not really possible to fall off the end of the function (see [microsoft/TypeScript#21985](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21985) for more info).

All of this works with no error.  Whether or not it's worth the complexity of refactoring is up to you.

---

Note that you don't have to make these `Shape`-specific.  You could abstract the type guard functions so that you also pass in the name of the discriminant key and it will work for any discriminated union.  It could look like this:

```
type SameDiscUnionMemberTuple<T extends any[], U extends T[number] = T[number]> =
  Extract<U extends unknown ? { [K in keyof T]: U } : never, T>;

function hasSameType<T extends object[], K extends keyof T[number]>(shapes: T, typeProp: K):
  shapes is SameDiscUnionMemberTuple<T> {
  const sh: T[number][] = shapes;
  return sh.every(s => s[typeProp] === sh[0][typeProp]);
}

function hasType<T extends object[], K extends keyof T[number], V extends (string | number) & T[number][K]>(
  shapes: T, typeProp: K, typeVal: V): shapes is Extract<T, Record<K, V>[]> {
  const sh: T[number][] = shapes;
  return sh[0][typeProp] === typeVal;
}
function areEqual(...shapes: [Shape, Shape]): boolean {

  if (!hasSameType(shapes, "type")) return false;

  if (hasType(shapes, "type", "circle")) {
    return shapes[0].radius === shapes[1].radius;
  } else if (hasType(shapes, "type", "square")) {
    return shapes[0].sideLength === shapes[1].sideLength;
  }

  assertNever(shapes);
}
```

I'm not going to go over that in detail because this answer is long enough as it is.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBFJICWwALhAE4BmCyAwmTfBsgYaaZQJ4wIALiQByeK3YRRAbhI8aIACZkArlBHBVYAEa053JAF8i8itXqMkAZQCOqkDU7zeA4WKj3H0gzyRQyJQgAGQhgAHNKAAtNbT0aX2NTQwB6FKQoykoYDTTwsmjVHQA6eAB7MBSwMngaMqgyukoUgBU3a1qyGGayKChVaBSAJgBGAE4ADgBWeTpVYHhKMjLgJBA+2koAOQgAN1oACgAPTT3aAEpT-Zo8FyRouoB3JGAIZ4BRGjqaA4Aid6OgkWECUSHmTgQURAOg4ABokDpVJQkOEysiQEhdpgBiJfkgANQ2Sg0CjhY7nc6JEzEQz8QQ2KH0gC8SBYbA4SAAPjYvE4DPJQJBYFZrIyINYgWQ6DVbjS-HTkNZwOKxS1VDAOAAeFpICBHajAJRQBkgQQAbQAuvCAKq6-VhI0m5lOiAAPiQTLupABxIQlE1tr1BsdotNyAA-HgkGaANLkVYAawgfEaSBaFpEtqMSCutHhLVd-MMpDmCyWKwy6yVkDagm1duDxtD5otroOUDFGjTl38nfITeVzYgao1EG17q4flITkoqhoqw7YagxTOND47Y97uXCo9TJZi8EUDNAAYLcUFZS7tS7qXFstVlCoLWxzqgw6B5AhyOtUPLa74XGb6GsaLRmloui0BaZqiAqoitgcXq9kuIgtPCCoiDGdw9ge0D9kgPqKIs2rwrg9xuBhxh-rKU5IDOc4Lp2J4WuG55uLuLIKokpDXnKPC3uWqzeO8XgYAcxTiThXZmkO8JDhaPY6GUZQcCAqxcIhUpIAcACEj7VsObjtp2FK0RAs7zkgDAYFAEBFjRmkHI+z5GUu8K-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)